# Cannot assign value of type String to type UILabel

Tags: ios, swift

I have marked the part of my code where the problem is, it is commented out. The error message is:

> Cannot assign value of type String! to type UILabel!.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
        if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
            var sendingText = metadataObj.stringValue
            sendToDetailViewController.messageLabelDos = sendingText
        }
    }
}
```

The label it should be changing is in my DetailViewController and it is a label. The code above is from my original ViewController. How can I make this work?

More code to put in context:

```
if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self)
}

func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
        if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
            var sendingText = metadataObj.stringValue
            sendToDetailViewController.viaSegue = sendingText
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `String` instead of setting text to label, because when you correct it and set like this `sendToDetailViewController.messageLabelDos.text = sendingText`, you will get nil error because `messageLabelDos` is not initialize yet, so try like this. Create one string instance in `DetailViewController` and use that inside `prepareForSegue` for passing String and then use that `String` instance in `viewDidLoad` to assign `Label` to text.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    //Your other methods

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
        if segue.identifier == "SendDataSegue" {
            if let sendToDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? DetailViewController {
                var sendingText = metadataObj.stringValue
                sendToDetailViewController.messageDos = sendingText
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `DetailViewController`

```
var messageDos: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.messageLabelDos.text = messageDos
}
```

Comment: that sure made the error go away, but I am unfortunately not changing the label on the DetailViewController? See more of my code above, as I have updated your post.

Comment: this is my instance `var viaSegue = ""` and this is inside the viewDidLoad: `self.messageLabelDos.text = viaSegue`

Comment: Should I put all of my code in my question, so you can see?

Comment: I have tried putting it outside of every other method, but without luck :(

Comment: This part is being executed `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SendDataSegue", sender: self)


        }` 

But it just does not chance the label on the other viewcontroller, it is just blank.

Comment: I have now written the prepareForSegue function where you wanted me to, but then it gives me this error:
Use of unresolved identifier 'metadataObj' :(

Comment: Ok i will solve that error but you need to tell me the type of `metadataObj`, means which type of object it is, if it is custom class tell me the name of class.